# Problems with Android intents after activating app from background

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, background, google-cloud-messaging

I've just started with Android development. I've created an App Engine connected Android Project in Eclipse by following this guide: [Creating an App Engine Connected Android Project](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae?).

The app works, but when the task goes to background and then is activated again by receiving a GCM message, intents invoked by the GCMIntentService class do not reach the corresponding activity. What might be the problem?

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    [...]

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        sendNotificationIntent(context, "Message received via Google Cloud Messaging:\n\n" + intent.getStringExtra("message"), true, false);   
    }

    [...]

    private void sendNotificationIntent(Context context, String message, boolean isError, boolean isRegistrationMessage) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, RegisterActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("gcmIntentServiceMessage", true);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("registrationMessage", isRegistrationMessage);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("error", isError);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(notificationIntent);
    }

    [...]
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you acquiring wake lock when the message is received. If not do so. Also from design point of view you should be using pending intent. Because according to this code. The application will start when the message is received. If user is doing something else you cannot replace his task with your own.

Comment: How do I acquire a wake lock? What are pending intents? I am not familiar with Android development.

Comment: Acquiring wake lock did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
// add permission  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


         @Override
      public void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
         sendNotificationIntent(context, "Message received via Google Cloud Messaging:\n\n" + intent.getStringExtra("message"), true, false); 
      context.sendBroadcast(intent) ; 
}

   private void sendNotificationIntent(Context context, String message, boolean isError, boolean isRegistrationMessage) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, RegisterActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("gcmIntentServiceMessage", true);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("registrationMessage", isRegistrationMessage);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("error", isError);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


     NotificationManager notificationManager = 
        (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     Notification notification = neNotification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Title",System.currentTimeMillis());

    PendingIntent intents = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context , context.getString(R.string.app_name), tickerText , intents );
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(100, notification);
}

    public class AppBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(intent.getAction() == "AppReceiver") {
       // this intent is gcminit intent and you can get data from this Intent

    }

}
```

}

```
   // in menifest file 
      <receiver android:name="AppBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="AppReceiver" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Modify text and notification icon

Comment: Thanks, this might solve the problem. But I think I have to differentiate between the app being active and staying in background. If I just add the code to my class, a symbol appears in the status bar, but the original message goes missing somewhere...

Comment: send broadcast when new message arrive.

Comment: I don't get along with the BrodcastReceiver... Where do I create and register it? How should the IntentFilter look like? I have just begun with Android development.

Answer (score 0):

If the activity is in background then the intent is receive in `onNewIntent` which will be called before onResume, thus you have to override onNewIntent

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    boolean b = intent.getBooleanExtra("gcmIntentServiceMessage", false);
    ........  
}
```

Comment: That is the problem... when the activity goes to background and is woken up by a GCM message, onNewIntent() is never be invoked anymore. Before the activity goes to background, onNewIntent() works as expected.

Comment: The activity may be killed by the sytem, so you need both the code in onCreate and in onNewIntent

Answer (score 0):

Issue almost solved... had to add:

```
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

There is only one problem left: onNewIntent() is still not fired when activity is brought to front by a GCM message. I put the code in onCreate() instead.